# Woo commerce Price is not showing the correct price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, price, storefront

I am new in e-commerce development, I'm facing an issue in woo commerce pricing, I have added 12 as product price and it is showing $547,072.00 as price, in fact, this value is visible in every price when we edit product than it shows the actual price which I have added due to this error when I add the product to cart is it adding $547,072.00 this as a product price.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCO8z.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frWbq.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpccT.png)

Please check this images for more clarifications

I'm using the latest WordPress and woo commerce version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an odd thing. It shouldn't happen. If it's happening then you probabily have a plugin interfering with woocommerce code (via hooks maybe?).

Try to disable all your plugin and change to a standard theme like storefront (if you can do it) and check if it start working again

Comment: I have tested it with a storefront theme but the price is the same also there is no hook added related to woo commerce cart, 
but the output is the same also when I update the price using quick edit by changing the price value then it is updating correctly, but I update without changing the value the price is same $547,072.00